# Check if App has DND permission on Flutter

Tags: flutter, permissions, do-not-disturb

How to check from Flutter app if it has DND permission. And if not how to enable the user to allow Do Not Disturb access for the App?

Already added

```
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
```

to Manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an existing library to handle this, so solution is to use [platform channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels).